Adding additional config results in 404 error
server_name example.com;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location ^~ /dashboard/ {
    alias /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

Above is a Nginx configuration. When https://example.com/dashboard/ is called, it properly shows the website from /var/www/html.  However, when following location / configuration is included, the same URL results in "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)" in the browser.
server_name example.com;

root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location ^~ /dashboard/ {
    alias /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

The fact that the website properly shows without location / tells me that it's not a permission issue nor a wrong path issue.
Inspecting the console shows the following errors:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)" for "main.3fbc94f0.js:1"
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)" for "main.d340c8f7.css:1"
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)" for "manifest.json".

Upon searching for these files, main.3fbc94f0.js:1  is located in "/var/www/html/static/js" and "main.d340c8f7.css:1" in "/var/www/html/static/css" and manifest.json in "/var/www/html/".

Your /dashboard/index.html file is probably loading other resources (CS,JS,IMG) using a URL without the /dashboard/ prefix. Check the access log to see the URLs for the resource files.

Could you explain that a bit further? https://example.com/ is not being used for anything related to accessing the website. https://example.com/dashboard/ works to access the website, until the last configuration is introduced. Are you saying /dashboard/ is loading other resources? The access log and the error log are not showing much info unfortunately.

Richard is right, the reason why it works without the second block is because in that case nginx simply serves files from the root directive, and it points to the right file file. You need to rebuild your web app with the correct base url, /bashboard, not /

The access log will tell you the URL for main.3fbc94f0.js:1. For example /main.3fbc94f0.js:1, /dashboard/main.3fbc94f0.js:1, or /static/js/main.3fbc94f0.js:1, etc. You need the URL to understand the problem.

The last item in the try_files is not a file path but URI:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Syntax:
try_files file ... uri;
try_files file ... =code;


If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

(that is, it redirects to /index.html, the second location block).
You can use the latter syntax (with =code one):
try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;


I'm a bit confused. Using this syntax directs the traffic to the 404 Not Found page. The question remains why does https://example.com/dashboard/ work until the second location block location /  is introduced?

try_files tries $uri (does not exist), $uri/ (does not exist), and finally does internal redirect to the /index.html location, and this uri matches the second location block (location /), thus the request proxy_pass'ed to the upstream.

I reproduced your configuration with =404 syntax, and it works as expected, if there is file that matches uri, it is served, otherwise the content of index.html is returned. Does /var/www/html/index.html exist?

Yes /var/www/html/index.html exists
